# Finding the V(speed) of a 12KG bucket in pulley with the law of conversation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation

A system of two paint buckets connected by a lightweight rope is released from rest with 12kg bucket 2m above the ground floor. Use the principle of conservation of energy to find the speed with which this bucket strikes the floor. You can ignore friction and the mass of the pulley.

[image: Sexy pully]

[image: Calculation]

[image: Calculation 2]

My thought here is that tension in the string is doing negative work on the 12KG box. I am then trying to use the law of conversation of energy on the 12KG box to find the end V of the 12KG box.

I personally think that 1 Joul is very little but I don't think my math is wrong. It's more my logic.

The answer is 4.4 meters.

Comment: What's ur question?

Comment: I realized I wrote the question a little wrong. It's edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below (in the picture) is my attempt to work the Atwood's machine via conservation of energy.

[image]

Comment: I found a video doing it exactly like this some short time ago, so you are very right sir. I can understand that we are thinking about the whole system here. Is there a way to do this thinking about only one of the objects, one of the masses? I think that would be a much more intuitive way of solving the problem to me. Thanks for using your time to help me.

Comment: The second mass is intimately involved with your answer.  One way or another, you will have to account for the second mass's change in potential and kinetic energy.  I suggest you work several more problems in this area ... as you work more problems, the key concepts will come into focus.

Comment: Okey. Yes, I will work out a few more problems. I have one more question if you would be so kind, regarding springs. A spring has potential energy (as far as I understand). Why do we not say that the tip of the spring has kinetic energy, or what if the spring is 10 meter above the ground? Does it have kinetic energy then?

Comment: Different parts of the spring will be moving at different velocities, so the kinetic energy of a spring is normally not calculated.